# Sharepoint 2013 design manager - best practice to add files / css stylesheet / js javascript / images

Tags: 2013, css, design, design-manager

What's best practice to add stylesheet / js / images / files in the design manager?

What I have done:

- exported pretty mutch a standard design manager package from sharepoint (wsp)
- imported it into Visual studio 2012

One way I was thinking of was to add a mapped layouts folder and put all the files there in different folders (js / stylesheet ..) ? How can I refer to those files? Do I need to add those into a element.xml file as well to get the files deployed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add New Item and add Sharepoint/Office **Module** type in project
- Add the Folders and Files to the Module
- In the elements file use
  this format:-

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="Scripts" Url="Style Library/Scripts">
  <File Path="DataTableAssets\Scripts\jquery.js" Url="jquery.js" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
  <Module Name="Styles" Url="Style Library/Styles">
  <File Path="DataTableAssets\Styles\datatable.css" Url="datatable.css" Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
  </Elements>
  ```

Comment: how do I refer to files inside a module? I need to refer to those files from ex masterpage, pagelayouts... etc

Comment: Like so:-

<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="~SiteCollection/Style Library/Scripts/jquery.js" runat="server" />